# How to view image tooltips in IE?

Tags: internet-explorer

On some webpages, image tooltips can contain important information. One example is the [XKCD](http://xkcd.com) webcomic (where the tooltips are used for humorous captions for each comic), but there are others.

Is it possible to view these tooltips in IE on Windows Phone? And if so, how? Tap-and-hold on the image only shows options to save or share it. On a PC tooltips appear when you hover over an image with the mouse cursor, but of course that doesn't work on a touch-based device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems like this is not possible with out of the box IE functionality.

But you can have it making simple bookmarklet. In Internet Explorer, show the *three-dot context menu*, select *add to favorites* option. Type in some **name**, i.e. **_showTitles** and copy and paste this code to the **Web address** input (I used OneNote to get it inside my phone):

```
javascript:(function() {var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');for (i=0;i<imgs.length;i++){var parent = imgs.item(i).parentNode; var text = imgs.item(i).getAttribute('title'); var content = document.createTextNode(text); parent.appendChild(content);} })()
```

Currently it uses the `title` attribute of the `IMG` element and appends it after the `IMG` element.
Well, it is very simple and surely is error-prone. But it shouldn't be hard to alter that script to be better. Anybody is welcome to improve it.

I tried it in both desktop browser (Opera) and mobile browser (IE11 on WP8.1).

Comment: In the absence of a built-in option, this works well enough, thanks! BTW, an easy way to get the Javascript to your phone is to simply visit http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/3678 on it.